# How to write CSS for IE at stylesheet with other default styles

Tags: css, internet-explorer, responsive-design

I'm working with responsive website. I've used media queries for making that responsible. Basically, I haven't used any fixed width. I've used percentage as a width of every div.

So that the website can be scaled proportionally according to resizing of browser. For using percentage of wide may be caused problem for older ie. As ie prior to ie 9 don't support media query, so, I want to build the non-scalable version for those ie. As I gave only few code for bringing scalability, so is it okay if I write the CSS code at my main stylesheet under/at anywhere with my default CSS?

Like at `style.css`:

```
#info {
   width: 13.672%;
   /*if ie9 and lower
   width: 175px;*/
   height: 830px;
   /*if ie9 and lower
   margin-right: 40px;*/
   margin-right: 3.125%;
   float: left;
}

img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
  /*if ie9 and lower
   max-width: inherit*/
  height: auto;
  /*if ie9 and lower
   height: inherit*/
}
```

I want to write that format. But, I don't know the correct format. Please, tell me the correct format.

Another question to you. As those version of ie don't support the media-query, so the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link href="KT2012.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="kt_large.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:500px)" href="kt_small.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width:800px)" href="kt_tablet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:801px) and (max-width:1024px)" href="kt_medium.css" />
```

with `tablet.css`, `mobile.css` don't create any problems for those older version ie, isn't it? I mean I want to write IE special css only at my main stylesheet (`KT2012.css`). Should I write every IE special css at every stylesheet like at `mobile.css`, `tablet.css` etc? If that devised based css file don't support at older ie, so, I don't do any things with that device/viewport based stylesheet if I make non-scalable version for ie, isn't it?

Comment: just to clarify: Do you want IE9 included in this or not? (you say in the question text that you want it to work for "prior to IE9", but in the code comments you've put "IE9 and lower").

Comment: I want to make non-scalable version for IE6,IE7,IE8,IE9.
This is the website: http://abidhasan.zxq.net/KrisTobiassen2012
see, it scaled properly/proportionally according to the resizing of browser. I don't want at older ie. Because for using percentage as a width, older ie show's that problem: http://imgur.com/oXMEonN

On the other word, I want to turn off responsive special code for older ie(ie 1-9)

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend the approach taken by the HTML5 boilerplate, [outlined here by Paul Irish](http://misteroneill.com/journal/improved-internet-explorer-targeting-through-body-classes/). Basically, set up your document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

You now have classes in place to accurately target only certain versions of IE. Your css will look like this:

```
.element { margin-bottom: 20px; }
.lt-ie9 .element { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

You then avoid CSS hacks, and can keep everything in a single stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

IE <= 9 (is the only browser vendor that) supports them, which you can use to specifically target any version(s) of IE. For example

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
Special instructions for IE 9 here, for example load a specific CSS file to override rules only for IE 9
<![endif]-->
```

IE 10 has [dropped support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for them though.

More recently the [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) introduced a class based approach to avoid the multiple stylesheets (i.e. HTTP calls) issue and fragmented CSS rules that conditional comments tends to create.