# List of IE Specific html and CSS Tags/attributes

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, safari

Can i have a list of html/css tags which works only for Internet explorer.And these tags/attributes should not work in other browsers especially for chrome and safari.

Thanks,

Shyam

Comment: Have you tried this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019775/how-to-write-css-for-ie-at-stylesheet-with-other-default-styles

Comment: Hi Prashanth, Thanks for your response but i am not looking for conditional comments. Suppose there is a attribute "ALLOWTRANSPARENCY" . This works only for IE. In the similar way, i want to have a list of all attributes which supports only IE.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why or how do you expect to use that information?

Comment: The application(8 years old) which i am working on, is working only in IE.I am new to this app and My requirement is to make it browser agnostic. So , i want to identify if there are any IE specific tags/attributes that are used during its earlier development.

Comment: What scripting language is it using? if it's that old and it only works on IE, it wouldn't be surprising if it's using VBScript instead of JavaScript.

Comment: It's using java script only...

Comment: I'd say the issues are with the scripting and not with the HTML tags or the CSS as suggested in the question (but without seeing any code, it's just a guess). Even if the script is JavaScript, if the code is +8 years old, it's probably not standard (and won't work on other browsers). Anyway, good luck and let us know what you find.

Comment: Yea sure...will have a look at scripting also today..

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention the version of IE, I am Going with the IE10

this [link](http://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/) describes IE 10 Specific Styles

Answer (score 0):

I think the only HTML (non-standard) tag supported by IE and not other browsers is `<bgsound>` for background sound. Some sites will also mention `<marquee>` too, but although it is non-standard, it has worked on Chrome and Firefox for a while.

About CSS, I don't know if there are any specific rules/attributes that only work on IE (but I know there are many standard rules/attributes that do NOT work on older versions of IE :P)